# ion-select do not load the name again when I change tab

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

When I change tab, and then return to the old tab in ionic, the select field I had set becomes null, even with the page still loading and the var is populed.

```
<ion-header color="primary">
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Planilha</ion-title>
    <ion-item color="primary">
      <ion-label>Períodos</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="periodoSelecionado" (ionChange)="filtraPeriodo()">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let p of periodos" [value]="p">{{p.nome}}</ion-option>
        <b>p.nome</b>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-navbar>
  <ion-searchbar color="primary" (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
</ion-header>
```

In this case, when I change tabe, the p.nome do not reload when I return to the tab, only if I click on it again.

TS file:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.storage.get('apenasMinhasAtividades').then((confApenasMinhasAtividades) => {
    if (confApenasMinhasAtividades == null) {
      this.confApenasMinhasAtividades = false;
    } else {
      this.confApenasMinhasAtividades = confApenasMinhasAtividades;
    }
  });
  this.getPlanilha(true, true);
}

getPlanilha(carregarBanco?: boolean, filtraPeriodo?: boolean) {
  if (filtraPeriodo == true) {
    this.filtraPeriodo();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `ts` code?

Comment: Please put that on your original question with `code` formating.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this method `this.getPlanilha(true, true);` inside the `promise` as shown below.

*.ts*

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.storage.get('apenasMinhasAtividades').then((confApenasMinhasAtividades) => {
      if (confApenasMinhasAtividades == null) {
        this.confApenasMinhasAtividades = false;
      } else {
        this.confApenasMinhasAtividades = confApenasMinhasAtividades;
      }
      this.getPlanilha(true, true);
    });

  }
```

Comment: Diden't work. I will look for more options and return with answer. Thank you anyway.